# What is the key or command to fold siblings' code in GoLand?

Tags: intellij-idea, goland, code-folding

In unit tests, we specify large, deeply-nested structures as data and as expected values.
I have learned about folding the current block with C-minus and C-period (one is named Collapse and one is named Fold, which seems like a distinction without difference), and fold everything with Shift-C-minus

I want to fold everything at the same level as the cursor: the siblings. I cannot find a key or menu command to do so

Thanks in advance

I looked in the help system and searched online for (GoLand | idea ide) code fold siblings

Answer (score 0):

There's no "Collapse Siblings" action, but you can use *Code->Folding->Expand All to Level* on a selection to achieve a similar result.

Comment: how can I request this feature?